# Django Error: OperationalError: no such table: polls_poll

Tags: python, django, shell, sqlite

Going through Django tutorial 1 using Python 2.7 and can't seem to resolve this error:
**OperationalError: no such table: polls_poll**

This happens the moment I enter `Poll.objects.all()` into the shell.

Things I've already tried based on research through the net:

1) Ensured that `'polls'` is listed under `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

Note: I've seen lots of suggestions inserting `'mysite.polls'` instead of `'polls'` into `INSTALLED_APPS` but this gives the following error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'polls' from 'mysite'**

2) Run `python manage.py syncdb` . This creates my db.sqlite3 file successfully and seemingly without issue in my mysite folder.

3) Finally, when I run `python manage.py shell`, the shell runs smoothly, however I do get some weird Runtime Warning when it starts and wonder if the **polls_poll** error is connected:
**\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py:63: RuntimeWarning: SQLite received a naive datetime (2014-02-03 17:32:24.392000) while time zone support is active.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you first ran `python manage.py syncdb` did the shell output that it created the Poll table?

Comment: It does the following:
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
  Apply all migrations: (none)
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations needed.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Comment: That means you are running django trunk. To simplify getting started, consider using django 1.6.x.  Just pip install django

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I meet the same problem today and fix it I think you miss some command in tutorial 1 just do follow: 
`./python manage.py makemigrations polls`
`python manage.py sql polls` 
`./python manage.py syncdb`

then fix it and gain the table polls and you can see the table created you should read the "manage.py makemigrations" command

Comment: polls is actually the name of the app listed under INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: It is important to point out that it is almost always better to type `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` as opposed to `python manage.py makemigrations` since sometimes, not all applications are picked up - this happened to be the case for me, because I had made a lot of manual modifications to the underlying code, app directory names etc. Sometimes, django can get "out of sync" - and so its always best to **explicitly** state the application whose model is to be migrated.

Answer (score 9):

i figured out the mistake you did, after making changes to your models.py you should run migrate ..i.e

```
    python manage.py migrate
```

then only your changes(polls_question) will be visible

Answer (score 2):

For those encountering this error in the current django 3.0 release (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/), you can rectify it by making sure you've run the following commands in order.

`python manage.py makemigrations polls`

`python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001`

`python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved this problem in a very easy and effective way.

This error is coming because of wrong **pycache** and db.sqlite3 in django
To solve this error we can delete those files and re-make it.

Delete **pycache** and db.sqlite3 manually.

then run this in terminal:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

After this your database and __pycache will be created again. And just make migrations, it will work fine.

Of course you might want to store your data before deleting database.